# a bash command generates strange behavior

Tags: bash, command

I am learning bash and happened to type `var = "$(cat)"` in bash, the strange thing is it enters and bash prompt disappeared until I use *ctrl-c*.

what is the command `var = "$(cat)"`?

```
bash-3.2$ var = "$(cat)"

^C
bash-3.2$
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Writing `var=$(cat)` means that you're trying to store the output of a subshell that executes the command `cat`. However, executing `cat` without arguments is equivalent to `cat STDIN` (also the same as `cat -`), and if you don't properly terminate the input flow, `cat` will still read from `STDIN` until it is interrupted (that's why you think your prompt disappeared but, actually, you're in the subshell).

Since you're sending the `SIGINT` signal (`CTRL+C`) to the (sub)process, the command, and thus the subshell, exits with a non-0 status (you can check the exit status executing `echo $?` just after `var=$(cat)`, it should be equal to 130 for a process terminated by `SIGINT`). Alternatively, you can try to write something to the `STDIN` of the aforementioned subshell and then send `CRTL+D`, which when typed at the start of a line on a given terminal signifies the end of the input, instead of `CTRL+C`. Finally, you can type `echo $var` in order to check if the variable assignment did work as expected.

Comment: Correction: there's no subshell. The command in `$()` is simple enough that bash does't bother with one, just runs the `cat` command as a subprocess. (And it's `cat`, not a subshell, that's taking input without giving any prompt.) Also, if the question is literally right, there are spaces around the "`=`", which changes the command's meaning significantly.

Comment: Interesting. AFAIK process substitution invokes a subshell (child process of the parent shell, thus a subprocess?). Has bash any mechanism in order to choose wheter to exectue just the command or a whole instance of the command interpreter based on the complexity of a given command? Regarding the spaces, I guessed (by default) it was miswritten. But yeah, totally agree with you.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is exactly right, but it seems to only create a subshell if there's any more than a single basic command, so `$(cat)` just runs `cat` directly, but `$(cat | cat)` and `$(cat; cat)` both create a subshell (that then runs two instances of `cat` in appropriate configuration). BTW, `bash`, `zsh`, and `dash` all seem to do it this way.

Comment: As the for the command in the original: `var=$(cat)` and `var="$(cat)"` both do what you describe, but `var = "$(cat)"` tries to run the command `var` with "=" as its first argument, and the output of `cat` as its second.

Comment: We could well be talking about the very same thing, IMO the key is the "subshell" concept itself: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/442692/is-a-subshell, https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/261638/is-a-sub-shell-the-same-thing-as-a-child-shell and https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Command-Substitution.html (BTW, in my above comment, I meant COMMAND substitution not process substitution).

Comment: But check out what it actually does. Try `var=$(ps -xj -g$$); echo "$var"` (this will show your shell process with the `ps -xj` command running directly as a subprocess) versus `var=$(ps -xj -g$$ | cat); echo "$var"` (this will show your shell, a subshell process, and the `ps -xj` and `cat` running as subprocesses of the subshell).